# Why do I keep Getting CORS Error in Springboot Application After Enabling CORS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

My server application built with springboot keeps giving CORS error, I have tried all I can and even downgraded the to java 11 from java 17 but still not working.

I keep getting this when i try to test with safari console.

[blocked] The page at https://www.google.com/?client=safari&channel=mac_bm was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:3000/api/v1/userapi/auth/app-status.

and this

Not allowed to request resource

and this

Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/userapi/auth/app-status due to access control checks.

here is a sample of my web security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    private final UserModelDetailsService userModelDetailsService;
    private final MyCORSFilter corsFilter;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationErrorHandler;
    private final JwtAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(new DBAuthenticationProvider(userModelDetailsService));
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/", "/*.html", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/h2-console/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()

                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)

                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationErrorHandler)
                .accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/*.html", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/documentation/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v3/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

and also i tried using custom filter, still did not work.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        System.out.println("i am here 000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH, PUT, HEAD");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
```

Comment: How are you testing on the Safari console?

Comment: fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/userapi/auth/app-status"), I make use of the fetch method. it works fine on postman and swagger.

Comment: Effectively you are trying to fetch some content from your API at localhost from within the google.com home page. While that page has CORS restrictions you will not be able to do that and any browser will block you.

Comment: Yes, even with the remote server the frontend, using react, is still complaining about having CORS error. He has not been able to consume any API

Comment: in your first example you have enabled spring cors filter `cors()` and ALSO added a custom corsFilter, why do you need 2 filters for? also where are all your logs? where are your debug logs? where are your browser logs? Please read the spring security CORS chapter before asking on stack overflow